VSCode can't detect the import of lombok in gradle project: `The import lombok cannot be resolved: Java(268435846)`
I'm trying to use VSCode to develop a gradle project. I've installed the following VSCode extension:

Gradle for Java
Gradle Language Support
Language Support for Java
Project Manager for Java

But sadly, the import can't be resolved. I'm failimar with LSP in C/C++ but not in java. The following questions are what I'm interested in and may help to illstruate the problem better:

What's the relationship between Gradle for Java and Language Support for Java? I think Language Support for Java won't work if it doesn't know the dependency in build.gradle
How do I print the debug info in Language Support for Java for what packages are indexed?

This is my build.gradle:
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation libs.junit.jupiter

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation libs.guava

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.3'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'

}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'moso_blog.App'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


Please help me to resolve the missing lombok dependency

There is the IDE's warning window: https://imgur.com/a/FpN55G6

Based on the lombok docs, you need the MS Extension Pack for Java. It is not entirely clear for me which one of the included plugins contains Lombok support, so perhaps this will not help you, but it's worth a shot.

Actually, the lombok support is listed as a feature of the Language Support for Java by Red Hat plugin (part of the MS pack, but obviously available as a standalone plugin, too). Do you have that one, or another one? This one should support Lombok, the others likely not.

Thanks, I think it's a problem with the Language server's cache. I press F1 in VScode, and run Java: clean Java language Server workspace. And it can work normally

Check whether your project is Imported:

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P).
Run Java: Import Java Projects.
Ensure the project and dependencies are correctly imported.

Check your language server Logs:

Open the Output panel (Ctrl+Shift+U or Cmd+Shift+U), then select Java
Language Server from the dropdown.
Look for any errors or warnings related to dependency resolution.

If this doesn't help, you could restart VSCode or Java Language Server. You could also clean the cash of Java Language Server by using shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace".


That's exactly what I want!
